# Multiple checkbox in list and is check in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I've got a question, I have a list of checkbox in combobox box and it looks like this:

```
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding CandidateEntity}">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SkillSetEntities, ElementName=CrudCandidate }"
                                IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Umiejętności">
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </StackPanel>

                 </StackPanel>
```

Now I also have a collection of skillset objects in binded item source (CandidateEntity.SkillSets), now how can I check those checkboxes that are in my collection of skillset objects?

I want to create a edition for CandidateEntity object in form and part of that edition is list of skillset that is represented in combobox.

EDIT:

I have solved problem by adding to skillset model prop:

```
 private bool _isSelected = false;

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return this._isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
        }
    }
```

And then in view model:

```
    private List<SkillSet> GetSkillSets()
    {
        var skillsetList = this._catalog.SkillSets.ToList();
        var candidateSkillsetList = this.CandidateEntity.SkillSets.ToList();
        foreach (SkillSet skillset in skillsetList)
        {
            foreach (SkillSet candidateSkillset in candidateSkillsetList)
            {
                if (skillset.id == candidateSkillset.id)
                {
                    skillset.IsSelected = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return skillsetList;
   }
```

and in checkbox in wpf:

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
```

BUT I am pretty sure there must be easier way to handle that, is there?